# Determine if a quotient ring meets various definitions

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z}$. Give justified answers to the following:
>
> 1. List the zero-divisors of $R$.
> 2. List the elements of $R$ that have a multiplicative inverse.
> 3. List the subrings of $R$.
> 4. Is $R$ an integral domain?
> 5. Is $I=\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12\}$ an ideal of $R$?
> 6. Does $I$ have a multiplicative identity element?
> 7. Find and ideal of $R$ having only two elements.

**Solution**

1. An element $a$ of a ring $R$ if $a\ne0$ there exist $b\in R$, $b\ne0$ such that either $ab=0$ or $ba=0$. Our zero-divisors are $2,4,6,7,8,10,12$. As
2. The elements of $R$ that have a multiplicative inverse are $\{1,3,5,9,11,13\}$. An inverse is defined as $x\times x^{-1}=e$, where $e$ is the identity for multiplication, which is $1$.
3. If S is a subring of $R$ it contains e and hence also contains $e,2e,3e,...$ However these elements are $1+14Z,2+14Z,3+14Z....$ In other words $S$ contains all the elements of $R$ and so $S=R$.
4. Our ring is not an integral domain as we have zero-divisors.
5. The number of elements of an ideal must divide 14. So our ideal must have 2 or 7 elements. I has 7 elements and can be generated by 2, making it a cyclic group. I is an ideal of R.
6. No it does not, the multiplicative identity of $R$ is $1$.
7. The subring of order $2$ is ${0,7}$.

> What mistakes have I made for all parts?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. There are other elements that have a multiplicative inverse besides the two you listed

Comment: What would the other elements be?

Comment: $1,9,11,$ and $13$

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of multiplying to values larger than $15$ for some reason. How does the rest of the questions look?

Comment: also, you did not list all of the zero divisors; and to find subrings, what are the possible orders of additive subgroups of $\Bbb Z/14\Bbb Z$?

Comment: So I have just updated the zero-divisors. I will update part 5 and 7 accordingly. Then find part 3.

Comment: and while it is true the elements in a proper ideal should not be invertible, the ideal does not have to contain *all* of the ring's non-invertible elements; also, {$0, 2$} is not an ideal because it is not closed under multiplication (does not contain $2+2=4$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Correct. Do you have a proof as well?
2. Incorrect; there are more units. In particular, the multiplicative identity is *always* a unit.

A nice general fact about finite rings, which you may be able to prove for yourself, is the following:

> In a **finite** unital ring, every nonzero element is either a zero divisor or a unit.

3. **Big hint:** A subring must contain $1$ by definition, and hence also $1+1$, and $1+1+1$, etc.
4. Correct.
5. Your reasoning fails since you have updated your answer to part 1; reconsider your answer.
6. Correct.
7. Incorrect; this set is not closed under addition, and not closed under multiplication by elements of $R$.
   **Big hint:** For each element $x$ of the ideal, the set
   $$xR=\{0,x,2x,\ldots,13x\},$$
   is a subset of the ideal, and hence consists of at most two elements.

Comment: 1. Yes I can prove it. 2. $1,3,5,9,11,13$. 5. It is an ideal (edited question).

Comment: 3, If $S$ is a subring of $R$ it contains $e$ and hence also contains $e,2e, 3e...$. However these elements are $1+14\mathbb{Z},2+14\mathbb{Z},3+14\mathbb{Z}...$. In other words $S$ contains all the elements of $R$ and so $S=R$

Comment: 5. The number of elements of an ideal must divide $14$. So our ideal must have $2$ or $7$ elements. $I$ has $7$ elements and can be generated by $2$, making it a cyclic group. $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: 7. The subring of order $2$ is $\{0,7\}$